# SQL optimization for getting points per user

Tags: c#, sql

I have a code that I really need some advice on how to optimize.

I have over 10,000 users and 1,000,000 codes in the system so this takes way too long.

Any help is appreciated:

```
 List<User> userResults = (from u in myDB.Users
                   select new
                   {
                       User = u,
                       Sum = (from tc in myDB.TriviaCodes
                              where tc.userID == u.userID &&
                              (tc.dateRedeemed.Value.Hour < 20 ? tc.dateRedeemed.Value.Date == date.Date : tc.dateRedeemed.Value.Date == yesterday.Date)
                              select tc).Sum(p => p == null ? 0 : p.pointsGained)
                   })
           .OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum)
           .Where(g => g.Sum != 0)
           .Select(g => g.User)
           .Take(100)
           .ToList();
```

here are the SQL's of the two relevant tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TriviaCodes] (
    [TriviaCodeID]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [codeNumber]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [dateRedeemed]      DATETIME       NULL,
    [answeredCorrectly] BIT            NULL,
    [pointsGained]      INT            NULL,
    [questionNumber]    INT            NULL,
    [userID]            INT            NULL,
    [triviaPrizesCodes] INT            NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TriviaCodeID] ASC)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [userID]       INT            NOT NULL,
    [UDID]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [firstName]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [lastName]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [cellNo]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [address]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [city]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [zip]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [creditCode]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [GameThriveID] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [homeNumber]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([userID] ASC)
```

Comment: This really isn't very helpful. We need to see the actual T-SQL being generated, and, preferably, the query plan being generated.

Comment: I did not understand any of the things you have said.

Comment: Without extra detail as suggested by Randy, there's not a lot we can do to help, other than perhaps suggesting keeping the users total scores aggregated in the database rather than summing up every time.

Comment: What extra detail do you need and how can I find it? I'm working with Visual Studio. All the data behind the tables was created automatically with a .dbml file

Comment: You can get the SQL generated by linq using the [Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Please update the question with at least the SQL.

Comment: I've updated the question. Is that the SQL you were looking for?

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework? If so, replace the `.ToList()` with a `.ToString()` then copy and paste the resulting string in to this question.

Comment: Try using a tool like LINQPad which helps you play with the SQL generated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should add foregin key to userID field of table TriviaCodes.
Then try somthing like this:

```
        var userResults =
            (
                from u in myDB.Users
                join tc in myDB.TriviaCodes on u.userID equals tc.userID

                where
                    (tc.dateRedeemed.Value.Hour < 20
                        ? tc.dateRedeemed.Value.Date == date.Date
                        : tc.dateRedeemed.Value.Date == yesterday.Date)
                select new
                {
                    u,
                    tc
                }
            )


       .GroupBy(k => k.u.userID)
                .Select(group => new
                {
                    user = group.First().u,
                    points = group.Sum(p => p.tc.pointsGained)
                })
       .OrderByDescending(u => u.points)
       .Where(u => u.points > 0)
       .Select(u => u)
       .Take(100)
       .ToList();
```